# Unsetting the lowest set bit in asm

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

The following is the function I've come up with to unset the lowest 1-bit in a number.

```
unset_lowest_bit:
    # NUM & (NUM-1)
    # All binary digits to the left of the first 1 will remain unchanged, so & itself=itself
    # Any zeros to the right of the first 1 will stay zero, since anything & 0 = 0
    # And finally, the first 1 will go to zero, since the -1 will eventually need to borrow
    # Up to the first 1 digit
    lea -1(%rdi), %rax
    and %rdi, %rax
    ret
```

Other than not using a function call for this, is this a good implementation of unsetting the lowest bit? Or is there an instruction that does this (it seems like a pretty non-standard thing to do, so couldn't find any instruction).

Comment: Again, ask a compiler.  That's what gcc and clang emit (or `blsr` with `-march=skylake` for example).  https://godbolt.org/z/4e8b15.  Many of these simple questions that a compiler can answer seem like clutter on Stack Overflow, and like you're not putting much effort in before asking.  IDK if it would be better to combine multiple bit-hacks into one question; probably not except for all the related set/clear/flip a single bit with bts / btr / btc.

Comment: But do note that BMI1 does have a few more lowest-set-bit instructions.  I hope you aren't going to ask separate questions about each of those, too.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ - their mnemonics all start with bls...  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#BMI1_(Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_1).

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the feedback and the links. I tried with the `-O3` with the compiler (which gave something pretty similar to what I asked) but didn't know about adding in the `-march=skylake` to get the `blsr`, Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You didn't mention in your question that you'd already checked compiler output and found this was what they did.  But yeah, in general if you wonder if there might be a new instruction, use a recent `-march=` like skylake, znver2, or even icelake-client to see if the compiler uses different instructions.  (If it doesn't, that's not proof there isn't one, though, especially for SIMD instructions with auto-vectorization.)  That's basically the only non-obvious thing here, and why I didn't downvote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an instruction for that, but it's not in the base instruction set, it's in BMI1: [`blsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr)

BMI1 is implemented by Haswell and newer on the Intel side (excluding Atom), and Jaguar&Piledriver and newer on the AMD side.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion. If it's common enough to be an instruction, what is the usage of unsetting the lowest set bit?

Comment: @David542 for example iterating through the set bits of a BitSet, or testing whether a number is a power-of-two (especially if zero is allowed/ignored), it can be used in Fenwick trees